# Use of owl carousel in opencart v3

Tags: javascript, html, css, twig, opencart-3

I want to use owl-carousel in opencart 3.0.2. So I have downloaded it from https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/index.html. How can I do the same? Where do I have to put the files downloaded from the given link?

Distributed version structure given below:

owlcarousel/

├── assets/

│   ├── owl.carousel.css

│   ├── owl.carousel.min.css

│   ├── owl.theme.default.css

│   ├── owl.theme.default.min.css

│   ├── owl.theme.green.css

│   ├── owl.theme.green.min.css

│   └── owl.video.play.png
│
├── owl.carousel.js

├── owl.carousel.min.js

├── LICENSE-MIT
└── README.md
[opencart file structure image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hmOHg.png)

Answer (score 1):

You should upload it to /catalog/view/javascript/.

If you are using default template and if you want to respect OpenCart coding standards and want to use this JS plugin only in one theme, you can upload css files to /catalog/view/theme/default/stylesheet/ or in custom template path of its css.

Then you should point to needed files in your template header file (/catalog/view/theme/default/template/common/header.twig)